# LNK2019: Unresolved External Symbol ... Referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, function, file-io, multidimensional-array

I am taking an introductory programming class, so I hope this issue isn't too terrible. I have fixed all of the problems in my Main function so far, but then I uncommented my Blob function call and an error came up that I apparently just can not figure out. I have researched it already and have not found anything that fits my problem well enough.

I believe it has something do with the **'s that I added to fix a previous problem with my 2D array (which is required for the assignment). I have included the comments at the top of the code to clarify the objectives of the program.

The error is:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Blob(char *
>   *,int,int)" (?Blob@@YAXPAPADHH@Z) referenced in function _main    c:\Users\Laura\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\pr9_lt12e\pr9_lt12e\p9_lt12e.obj

Also, the first line of the array that is output is offset 10 spaces to the left. Column 13 should have an 'X', but it shows up at 3. I have changed the values of the array manually so that arr[0][12] = 'X' (before the array is printed out) but the position did not change. I can still use the program without this being fixed because it will only be a few points off.

My entire code is:

```
/*
         SUMMARY 
           This program will read in data from a file and store it in a two-dimensional array. 
           From there it will detect all of the groupings of characters, or "blobs", in the file and count them.

         INPUT 
           The program will read in information from a file called "blob.txt".

           BAD DATA CHECKING: 
                N/A

         OUTPUT 
            The program will output the amount of blobs in the file.

         DATA STRUCTURES
            N/A

         ASSUMPTIONS  
          -The file will have 20 records. Each record will be 70 characters long and the character 
            will be either an X or a blank space/whitespace.

*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>    
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//GLOBAL CONSTANTS
const int   ONE_D = 22,
            TWO_D = 72,
            SEVEN = 7;

const char  X = 'X',
            B = ' ';

//FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
void Blob(char**, int, int);    //Retrieves data from the file and places it into the array


//MAIN FUNCTION
int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    ifstream file;

    string line;

//  char character;

    int index1 = 0,
        index2 = 0,
        col1 = 0,
        col2 = 0,
        blobCount = 0;

    //Declare the 2D array. From course website.
    char ** arr;
    arr = new char * [ONE_D];
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < ONE_D; index1++)
        arr[index1] = new char [TWO_D];

    //Welcome message
    cout << "Welcome to the Recursive Blob Finder program!\n\n";

    //Open the file
    file.open("blob.txt");

    //Check to see if file has been opened
    if (file.is_open())
        cout << "The file has been opened!\n\n";
    else
        cout << "The file has not been opened!\n\n";

    //Read in data from the file and write to the array
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < 20; index1++) {
        getline(file, line);
        strcpy_s(arr[index1], 72, line.c_str()); 
    }

    ////Row 1 is offset by -10. Adjust first row.
    //arr[0][2] = B;
    //arr[0][12] = X;

    //Clear non-'X' cells
        for (index1 = 0; index1 < 22; index1++) {
            for (index2 = 0; index2 < 72; index2++) {
                if (arr[index1][index2] != X)
                    arr[index1][index2] = B;
            }
        }

    //Print numbered lines
    for (col1 = 1; col1 < 8; col1++)    
        cout << "         " << col1;

    cout << endl;

    for (col2 = 1; col2 < 8; col2++)    
        cout << "1234567890";

    cout << endl;    //EDIT IS HERE

    //Print array
    for (index2 = 0; index2 < 20; index2++) {

        for (index1 = 0; index1< 70; index1++)
            cout << arr[index2][index1];

        cout << endl;
    }

    //Search array for 'X' characters
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < 20; index1++)     {

        for (index2 = 0; index2 < 70; index2++) {

            //When X is found, add 1 to blob count. Blob function will clear out the remaining blob characters
            if (arr[index1][index2] == X)   {
                blobCount++;
                Blob(arr, index1, index2);
            }
        }
    }

    //Close the file
    file.close();

    return 0;

}


//OTHER FUNCTIONS   

//Name: Blob
//Description:  Recursive function to find and clear each blob.
void Blob(char **c[ONE_D][TWO_D], int row, int col)  
{
        //Eliminate one blob at a time

    //Potential positions for 'X' after clearing the last X:         Ox
    //                                                              xxx


    if (**c[row][col]==X)   {
        **c[row][col] = B;

        //Test for X's connected to current blob
        if (**c[row][col+1]==X)
            Blob (c, row, col);

        if (**c[row+1][col-1]==X)
            Blob (c, row, col);

        if (**c[row+1][col] == X)
            Blob (c, row, col);

        if (**c[row+1][col+1]==X)
            Blob (c, row, col);
    }   
}
```

Some things I have tried include changing the prototype:

```
void Blob(char** c[ONE_D][TWO_D], int, int);
```

function call:

```
Blob(arr[][], index1, index2);
Blob(arr[][72], index1, index2);
Blob(arr[22][72], index1, index2);
```

and function definition parameters:

```
void Blob(char c[ONE_D][TWO_D], int row, int col)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring a function called `blob(char **, int, int)`, and then later on change that declaration to `blob(char **c[ONE_D][TWO_D], int, int)`.

Given that you are indeed passing an `char **arr` to the function, I would suggest that you remove the `[ONE_D][TWO_D]` part, as that is essentially making your function take a 4 dimensional array [or a pointer to a pointer to a two-D array, possibly].

You will also need to change `**c[...][...]` into `c[...][...]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The program runs now. The file isn't opening (it was before) so I have to figure that out, but the big problem is fixed! :)

Comment: What had happened with the file was that I made a new copy of the program and forgot to put the file in the correct folder. Stupid mistake.